# Extract a string within "> and </ pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to extract the string from a file having following pattern within a line

```
>------ </
```

The ----- represents can be any variable length string. The start pattern within a line is `>` and end pattern `</`.

Using regex of VIM is command line search possible? and if so could that be printed?

Or will have to write a script?

I am a new user to VIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
%:s/.*>\(.*\)<\/.*/\1/
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following vim search:

```
/">\(.*\)<\/
```

That should match any line with that pattern. It'll also store whatever text it grabs in between your start and end markers into `\1` which you can use if you want to do search and replace in vim. For example:

```
:%s/">\(.*\)<\//Log message: \1/
```

If you want to use grep in the command line to search for that string you can use:

```
$ egrep "\">.*<\/" foo.txt
```

This will print out only the matching lines from `foo.txt`. If you want to send these to a new file try:

```
$ egrep "\">.*<\/" foo.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: I need the highlighted text only to stay and rest all data should get deleted or whatever text grabbed could that be redirected to any other file?

Comment: Probably one more non-greedy solution?